# replace source dir with destination in find result

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm trying to update an archive by replacing only the changed file once.

I have the following script, I'm trying to run the `find` command and copy the files using the `install` command.

I have some error when trying to replace the source dir by the destination in find result `{}`.

I see two options: remove the source dir from the result, and append the destination dir, or replace it using the `sed` style.
I want it to keep working when the source and destination variable will be changed, so using the `cut` command not seem to me right if it works with fixed numbers.

Can someone help with this?

This is my script: (currently, I'm getting bad substitution for the `${{}#"$SRC"}` in the find line)

```
SRC=/root/src/dir
DEST=/root/dest/dir
TS1=/root/src/ts/timestamp1
TS2=/root/src/ts/timestamp2
ERR=/root/src/ts/error

if [ ! -f  "$TS1" ]; then
  touch -m -a -t 197001010000.00 "$TS1"
fi

touch "$TS2"

find "$SRC" -type f -newer "$TS1" ! -newer "$TS2" \( -exec install -Dvm 666 "{}" ${{}#"$SRC"} \; -o -exec touch "$ERR"  \; -a -quit \)  
if [ ! -f  "$TS1" ]; then
  mv -f  "$TS2" "$TS1"
else
  rm -f "$ERR"
fi
```

Comment: As -exec launches directly the 'install' executable, for performance consideration, it seems it would better to keep it that way and use a _prefix_/{} as 'install' destination. _prefix_/root/src would be then a symlink to the root destination /root/dst. It's somehow brittle as it needs and depends on a reliable symlink.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in comment, -exec launches directly the 'install' executable and for performance consideration it seems it would better to keep it that way.

Using a *prefix*/{} as 'install' destination with *prefix*/root/src/dir as a symlink to the destination /root/dst/dir will minimize the most I/O operations.

Using that in your script will give :

```sh
SRC=/root/src/dir
DEST=/root/dest/dir
TS1=/root/src/ts/timestamp1
TS2=/root/src/ts/timestamp2
ERR=/root/src/ts/error

#  Create symlink to destination with the /tmp as prefix
SRCROOT="$(dirname \"${SRC}\")"
mkdir -p "/tmp/${SRCROOT}"
[ -d "/tmp/${SRCROOT}" ] && ln -s "${DEST}" "/tmp/${SRC}";
[ -h "/tmp/${SRC}" ] || { echo "failed to symlink ..." ; exit 1; };

if [ ! -f  "$TS1" ]; then
  touch -m -a -t 197001010000.00 "$TS1"
fi

touch "$TS2"

find "$SRC" -type f -newer "$TS1" ! -newer "$TS2" \( -exec install -Dvm 666 "{}" "/tmp/{}" \; -o -exec touch "$ERR"  \; -a -quit \)  
if [ ! -f  "$TS1" ]; then
  mv -f  "$TS2" "$TS1"
else
  rm -f "$ERR"
fi

# Remove symlink
rm "/tmp/${SRC}"
rmdir "/tmp/${SRCROOT}"
```